# Android Studio: Can't see logs or system prints

Tags: android, android-studio

I have simple application created by Android studio wizard.

Here is the class of the only Activity created by Android studio wizard

```
package test.com.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("========> PRINT");
        Log.d("=====>", "PRINT");
        Log.i("=====>", "PRINT");
        Log.e("=====>", "PRINT");
        Log.v("=====>", "PRINT");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Application is running successfully on Note II.

Log level "verbose"
No filters.

Issue: can't see prints visible for filter "===>" or "PRINT".

"Enable ADB integration" does not change the described.
Studio version 1.2.1.1 running on mac os x.

UPDATE:

```
adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes ADB Logcat stops working, and clicking on "Restart" in "Android" tab will force it to work again

[image]

---

Also sometimes just restarting your mobile device will help, or the computer you are using

Comment: Thank you for joining the conversation. Just tried this, no changes

Comment: Maybe this activity is not used or not started.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about the same, but Android studio wizard for creating projects is producing only one activity and it is launched on project start.

Comment: By the way, if I produce some null pointer exception in this activity I am able to see it with "fatal" for filter. No information for ADB logs and Memory | CPU - all empty.

Comment: sometimes just restarting your mobile device will help, or the computer you are using

Comment: Device restart fixed the issue. Lost 2h with this.... really disappointed. Mosh, would you please update your answer with your last comment here, so I will be able to accept it as solution?

Answer (score -2):

I re-install the app until it works (max 3 times).

Comment: Thank you sir, I am reinstalling since 2h ago.